# A-frame rotate to a random rotation point

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, aframe, webvr

I have  some code using A-frame (https://aframe.io) that rotates a cube. What I'm wondering is how can I rotate the cube from a random amount anywhere from 0, 0, 0 to 360, 360, 360? Currently my rotation also loops so that it repeats after 1 second of being finished. What  I would like is to have my cube rotate to a random rotation and loop after a delay of 1 second each time. How can this be done? Code for the animation:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
      <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
      <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>

<a-entity animation="property: rotation; to: 20 0 0; loop: true; delay: 1000; dur: 1000">
        <a-box position="5 0 0" color="mediumseagreen"></a-box>
</a-entity>

      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```